# Saw this on Copacabana Beach Promonade in Brazil this week. What is it?

Tags: identification, trees

[image: Unknown tree]Taken in Brazil. What type of tree is this?

Comment: I assume some Ficus. many Ficus have *areal roots* (which eventually can touch soil and became root, or nearly a trunk. But I do not know well the genus (and I'm not sure about the leaves and fruits.

Comment: It is most likely a fig, possibly a Banyan from the shape of the roots.